# Movie about people trapped at motel

Tags: story-identification

The man is a convict about to be released despite his dangerous insanity.  This was I think 5-10 years ago. One of the characters from Goodfellas might have played the policeman who tries to unravel the mystery. There were I believe numerous killings. In the end

> they all turn out to be the same person

Comment: This doesn't sound like SFF.

Comment: If you add more details, your question may be eligible for migration to [movies.se], where it would be on-topic.

Comment: @Gallifreyan, I am trying to remember that tv mini series were there was an object .... involved with many places experiencing time and/or dimension and/or alt-reality. I believe it was centered on a motel and there were multiple violent deaths etc. BUT one would think the OP would have remembered a fair amount of what I just put here.

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya - What do you mean? This wasn't a miniseries, and there were no alternate timelines or dimensions.

Comment: @Adamant, you are viewing the question literally. There was a mini series that meet most everything in the question. The Good Fellows part.... maybe maybe not. Murder, Policeman/Detective investigates, unexplained things happen in the room, more violent deaths, more unexplained things, things begin to be understood. As I said, one would think the OP would have remembered some of that. IF this message helps the OP to remember more, is that a bad thing?

Comment: @Enigma - What about "they all turn out to be the same person"?

Comment: @Adamant "The man is a convict about to be released despite his dangerous insanity. This was I think 5-10 years ago. One of the characters from Goodfellas might have played the policeman who tries to unravel the mystery. There were I believe numerous killings. In the end" please identify where in the quoted question your question is stated?

Comment: @Enigma - Check the spoiler. ;-=

Comment: That's probably it, thanks.

Comment: @RobertGarner: I know you've been gone a year or so, but if you ever return, you can always accept your answers by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, even if they have been closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 23):

Sounds like the film **Identity**, where the people stranded at the hotel and picked off one by one turned out to be all multiple personalities emerging from the same guy. One such personality was played by Ray Liotta, of course well known as Henry Hill in Goodfellas.

Comment: Completely forgot about Ray Liotta, I just remember John Cusack.

Comment: Definitely correct. Nothing else could fit that description.